# Using "scold" in reported speech

Tags: reported-speech

Can I use *scold* in reported speech? For example,

> Mother **scolded** her children that they were too noisy.

Answer (score 9):

You can certainly use past tense *X **scolded** Y* to report what X did to Y.

But ***scold*** doesn't work the same as, for example, ***tell, inform, convince***, all of which can be followed by a subordinate clause giving more details of the action...

> *X **told** Y [that] it was raining*
>    *X **informed** Y [that] he was leaving*
>    *X **convinced** Y [that] it was true*

Note that the word ***that*** is effectively "optional" in all those examples, but that kind of ***that-*** clause [doesn't work well with ***scold***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scolded%20him%20that%2Cscolded%20him%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscolded%20him%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscolded%20him%20for%3B%2Cc0), where the normal syntax for OP's context is...

> *Mother scolded her children **for being** too noisy*

As is so often the case in English, there's no real shortcut to learning which prepositions and subordinate clauses can be used with specific verbs. You really just have to learn them by rote.

Comment: To me, *told/informed/convinced* define to some extent the information being communicated, therefore being applicable to reported speech. However, *scold* defines a mannerism, the tone of the communication rather than the content needed for reported speech.

Comment: Lots of verbs don't normally take ***that-*** clauses, including most or all "synonyms" of ***scold***, such as *rebuke, reprimand, reproach, reprove, admonish, chastise, chide, upbraid, berate* (to a greater or lesser degree). But there are many more transitive verbs with totally different meanings where the same syntactic constraint on "idiomacy" applies (I don't really think OP's usage is "ungrammatical"; it's just "non-idiomatic"). For *some* verbs, if the statement *A verbed B* can't be followed by *A verbed B **what**?* as a request for clarification, they fall into that category.

Comment: @FumbleFingers as a native speaker of (American) English, *scold that `complement`* sounds completely wrong to me. Moreover, a quick search of [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scolded+that%22&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=bks&biw=1920&bih=922) seems to show it never being used in this way.

Comment: @errantlinguist: You wouldn't often encounter *scold [direct object] that* in contemporary English, but it certainly *does* still occur (though my impression is it's less common than it was a century or two ago). But your quick search of Google Books would never have found much if anything - you'd need to include a direct object such as [*she **scolded us that** young ladies did not climb trees*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22scolded+us+that%22). That's from 2015 - it might be a bit "unusual/dated/formal", but imho (and in the opinion of the publishers) at least it's "valid".